# jQuery - Change button text without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change my button text as below, I have two select option, draft and publish. When I select to the draft option, button text must be change. But I can't change it without refreshing page. How can I do that ?

```
<body>
<button id="button" value=""></button>
<select name="select" id="draftOrPublish">
    <option value="0">Draft</option>
    <option value="1">Publish</option>
</select>
</body>
<script>
    var draftOrPublish = $('select#draftOrPublish').val();

    if (draftOrPublish == 0) {

        $('button#button').text('Save as Draft')

    } else if (draftOrPublish == 1) {

        $('button#button').text('Publish')
    }
</script>
```

Comment: encapsulate your script code into a function.  For the onchange attribute of the select, have it call the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the code inside `$(document).ready` and `$( 'select#draftOrPublish' ).change`

---

`$(document).ready` - A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready."

`$( 'select#draftOrPublish' ).change` - Bind an event handler to the "change" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $( 'select#draftOrPublish' ).change(function(){
     
  var draftOrPublish = $('select#draftOrPublish').val();

  if (draftOrPublish == 0) {

   $('button#button').text('Save as Draft')

  } else if (draftOrPublish == 1) {

   $('button#button').text('Publish')
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="button" value=""></button>
<select name="select" id="draftOrPublish">
 <option value="0">Draft</option>
 <option value="1">Publish</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to bring this into a function in order to assess whether or not the value of the select has changed. This is called an event, and you need an event listener attached to your `<select>` tag so that you can apply your event handler to change the text of the button. jQuery has a `.change()` function you can use to listen to the `<select>` tag

```
 var draftOrPublish = $('#draftOrPublish').val();    
 if (draftOrPublish == 0) {

      $('#button').text('Save as Draft')

  } else if (draftOrPublish == 1) {

      $('#button').text('Publish')
  }

$('#draftOrPublish').change(function () {
  var draftOrPublish = $('#draftOrPublish').val();
    console.log(draftOrPublish)
  if (draftOrPublish == 0) {

      $('#button').text('Save as Draft')

  } else if (draftOrPublish == 1) {

      $('#button').text('Publish')
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `change()` in jQuery to change text and value dynamically without page load.

```js
$('#draftPublish').change(function () {
  var draftPublish = $('#draftPublish').val();
  if (draftPublish === "0") {
      $('#btn').text('Save as Draft');
      $('#btn').val('draft');

  } else if (draftPublish === "1") {
      $('#btn').text('Publish');
      $('#btn').val('publish');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn" value="draft">Save as Draft</button>
<select name="select" id="draftPublish">
 <option value="0">Draft</option>
 <option value="1">Publish</option>
</select>
```